# Expected size of a set from union of sets with random elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I stumbled upon this problem and can't find a neat solution for arbitrary values of $k, m, n$.

Given $k$-sets of size $m: s_1 = \{a_1, \ldots, a_m\}, s_2 =\{b_1, \ldots, b_m\}, \ldots,s_k\{\diamondsuit_1,\ldots,\diamondsuit_m\}$ with randomly chosen elements from an alphabet of size $n$, $\diamondsuit$ being the $n$-th letter.

What is the expected size (and variance) of the set $s = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k s_i$

For $k = 2$ I have a solution, but I could not find anything for the general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $n$ letters. Let $X_{j}=1$ if letter $j$ belongs to set
$s=\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}s_{i}$ and $X_{j}=0$ otherwise.

Then the cardinality of $s$ equals $X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}$
so its expectation equals $\mathbb{E}\left(X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}\right)=\mathbb{E}X_{1}+\cdots+\mathbb{E}X_{n}$.

It remains to find $\mathbb{E}X_{i}=\mathbb{P}\left(\text{letter }j\text{ belongs to set }s\right)=1-\mathbb{P}\left(\text{letter }j\text{ does not belong to set }s_{i}\text{ for }i=1,\dots,k\right)$.

By independence of the sets and equal chances for the letters to belong to these sets we find:$$\mathbb E|s|=n\mathbb EX_1=n\times(1-(1-\frac{m}{n})^k)$$

Comment: Thanks, seeing it like this makes it a lot easier. I think the last line should be $$\mathbb E|s|=n\mathbb EX_1=n\times(1 - (1-\frac{m}{n})^k)$$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I repaired. Actually it is binomial: a letter is in it (success) or not (failure).